# How to change the name of an external table, stream and task?

Tags: stream, task, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, external

still new to snowflake,

But i have the task of changing the names of the external tables, streams and tasks? I really cant find anything on the internet in regards to it. All i need to do is change the name of each but its seems like the ALTER for the above doesnt include a renaming.
Thanks

Comment: Both tables and tasks have a `RENAME` option in the `ALTER` command.  Streams don't have a rename, but you can simply create a new stream over the newly renamed table, if that is your goal.

Comment: Hey mike, just want to say thank you for the help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: An example code could be: `ALTER TABLE db1.schema1.tablename RENAME TO db2.schema2.tablename;` But this is not applicable for TASK, they do not have RENAME parameter. I see only option to drop the TASK and re-create it.